# Why can't the compiler find the header file?

Tags: c, header

I am working in a linux environment. In my current directory, when I performed the ls command, this is what I got

[image]

In repo.c, I have this line of code

```
#include <battleship.h>
```

However when I try to compile and create the executable with this command(also link to library file battleship.c)

```
gcc repo.c -lbattleship.c
```

I get this error

"repo.c:10:24: error battleship.h: No such file or directory"

Does anyone know why the compiler cannot find the header file? I put it in the same directory as the main C file

Comment: Try to use #include "battleship.h", since battleship.h is a user defined library.

Comment: Your user define headers shuld written as #include "battleship.h" and system define header are different notation which is like #include<stdio.h>.

Comment: oh so only use <> for system libraries?

Comment: try to compile like this gcc -o lbattleship lbattleship.c

Comment: Isuru, not include repo.c at all?

Comment: sry for the mistake in my previous comment : battleship.h is a user defined header

Comment: `.h` aren't libaries, nor `.c` files are. Both files types typically contain source code. Libraries are binary files compiled out of source code.

Comment: alk .h is a header file though isn't it. Does that mean i just compile the battleship.c into object code to make it a library?

Comment: Just compiling it would create an object file (.o) which could be linked, yes.

Comment: alk so a library file is just an object file that could be linked to another?

Comment: Not quite, a libraries typically bundles a couple of object files (.o). See the object as the book compiled out of the authors thoughts (sources) and the library as ... well the library. :-) Library files typically end with either .a (static) or .so (shared).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# include<>
```

This variant is used to include system header files.

```
#include ""
```

This is used to include user created header files.

So try using

```
#include "battleship.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

M guess is that the following command compiles the project:

```
gcc -o battleship repo.c battleship.c
```

Theoretically the header file `battleship.h` should be included in `battleship.c` (or `repo.c`) like so (with quotes instead of brackets for local includes):

```
#include "battleship.h"
```

Comment: I *strongly* suggest compiling with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g repo.c battleship.c -o battleship`. Later on, learn how to use `make` with your `Makefile`