# How to address warning about function in header file?

Tags: c

This is concerning one of the functions in my header file(battleship.h). 
Here is the code for my function prototype

`int gameOver();`.

Inside my main C file, here is my code for using that function and including that header file

```
#include "battleship.c"
int main ()
{
      while(!gameover) 
      {
           ......
       }
}
```

When I tried compiling the main c file(repo.c) into object code with this command

```
gcc -c repo.c
```

I got the warning "the address of 'gameOver', will always evaluate as 'true'. Is there any way I can address this warning?

Comment: `#include "battleship.c"` ?

Comment: didierc user defined library. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773586/why-cant-the-compiler-find-the-header-file

Comment: read again: you include a `.c` file, not a `.h` file? I have nothing against that, just that it's somewhat unusual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably intended to call the function instead of simply taking its address:

```
while(!gameOver())
{
    ...
```

Note the parentheses.